# how do i make urls not duplicated in array js

Tags: javascript

at first im really noob still learning. i have an empty array if the user enters links in the input it's sends them to js so i used loop and then i store it in the array. but i want to make it not duplicated or send a message if there is duplicate url if user try enters url again how ? i googled and used stackoverflow i didn't find a solution yet here is some of my attempts.

```js
inputURL.forEach(e => {
  if (e.value === '') return alertText("failed", "You forgot URL empty", "showAlert2", "alert2")
  dropAlert("alert2");
  if (arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].length > -1) {
    checkLoop = true;
    console.log("no array exist so i push one!")
    alertText("success", "Successfully Saved!", "showAlert2", "alert2")
  }

  if (checkLoop === true) {
    if (arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].length > -1 < arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].length > -1) {
      arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value)
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].length; i++) {
        if (arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].length > 0) {
          // check if value exist in array;
          if (arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'][i].indexOf(e.value) > -1) {
            console.log("exist")
            existDoThis = true;
          } else {
            arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value)
            console.log("not exist")
            existDoThis = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (existDoThis) {
    alertText("failed", "There is a link already exist!", "showAlert2", "alert2")
  } else {
    alertText("success", "Successfully Saved!", "showAlert2", "alert2")
  }
})
```

the problem is that it print once , doesn't or sometimes spam. it really cracked my head a whole day seat on it (and sorry if my english is really bad tho)

Comment: you can use Set class to remove duplicate from an array.

Comment: like this: `const arrHasNoDuplicate = [...new Set(arrHasDuplicate)];`

Comment: @Layhout I don't understand u can u guide me how? in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to conditionally push item to array, you can try this:

```
inputURL.forEach(e => {
    if (e.value === '') return alertText("failed", "You forgot URL empty", "showAlert2", "alert2");
    dropAlert("alert2");
    if(!arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].some(a => a === e.value))
        arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value);
}
```

Comment: this actually worked for me tysm!

Comment: you learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

i assume `arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url']` is already an array, so hope this help:

```
inputURL.forEach(e => {
    if (e.value === '') return alertText("failed", "You forgot URL empty", "showAlert2", "alert2");
    dropAlert("alert2");
    arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value);
    arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'] = [...new Set(arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'])];
}
```

this way, `arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url']` will not have duplicate value.

Comment: but it keeps getting added everytime it's added to the array the problem here `arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value);` cuz this code is all on the function save and every user keeps pressing a button that adds the items in the array
'

Comment: yes `arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'].push(e.value)` will keep adding item, but `arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'] = [...new Set(arrEps[typeEp.innerText]['url'])]` will remove the duplicate item.

Comment: that's why i'd like to know how to check if there is already an duplicate in the array i think there is a condition to use but idk how to do it exactly

Comment: understood I'll try this method if it doesn't work I'll reply to u